# Finite Automata and Regular Expression

Tags: regex, regular-language, dfa, nfa

I'm stuck in writing a regular expression for a given language over the alphabet `{a,b}`. The strings are accepted if they start with the substring 'aa' or end with the substring 'bb.'

For example `{aab, abb, aaba}` are accepted but `{Λ, ab, abaa}` are not.

My attempted solution is: `{aa* + ab* + bb*}`, but I was thinking: what if the string started with a `b`? Then, my expression wouldn't work..

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple:

> Regular expression for language over the alphabet `{a,b},`string starts with sub-string `'aa'` or ends with the substring `'bb'`.

Regular Expression:

> `aa(a + b)* + (a + b)*bb`

Note `+` is union here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will probably work.

```
^aa[a,b]*|[a,b]*bb$
```

Comment: I don't think so, your solution enforces 'aa' and 'bb' at the end of every string, therefore 'ababb' wouldn't work

Comment: ^aa[a,b]*|[a,b]*bb$ means ^aa[a,b]* or [a,b]*bb$. So ababb will work for [a,b]*bb$. Maybe I didn't fully understand your question. Is the | sign allowed in your automata?